# Is there a simple way to convert data base rows to JSON in Golang

Tags: go

Currently on what I've seen so far is that, converting database rows to JSON or to `[]map[string]interface{}` is not simple. I have to create two slices and then loop through columns and create keys every time.

...Some code

```
tableData := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
  values := make([]interface{}, count)
  valuePtrs := make([]interface{}, count)
  for rows.Next() {
      for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
          valuePtrs[i] = &values[i]
      }
      rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)
      entry := make(map[string]interface{})
      for i, col := range columns {
          var v interface{}
          val := values[i]
          b, ok := val.([]byte)
          if ok {
              v = string(b)
          } else {
              v = val
          }
          entry[col] = v
      }
      tableData = append(tableData, entry)
  }
```

Is there any package for this ? Or I am missing some basics here

Comment: Have you try [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) ?

Comment: Converting rows to `[]map[string]interface{}` seems to be quite simple. I guess you try to achieve more than that. Why do you try to convert `v` to string?

Comment: @putu I did not try that, will give that a show

Comment: I think you should be able to move your `valuePtrs[i] = &values[i]` loop out of the `for rows.Next() { ... ` loop. That said, I have been drinking...

Comment: The ideal solution would be to define an iterator that wraps the sql.Rows() and produces JSON as it goes.

Comment: This should be significantly more performant, especially for larger tables (O(1) allocs instead of O(N)).

Comment: here are two Pakage will do
[gosqljson](https://github.com/elgs/gosqljson)
[go-jsonify](https://github.com/bdwilliams/go-jsonify)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm dealing with the same issue, as far as my investigation goes it looks that there is **no other way**.

All the packages that I have seen use basically the same method

Few things you should know, hopefully will **save you time**:

- database/sql package converts all the data to the appropriate types
- if you are using the mysql driver(**go-sql-driver/mysql**) you need to add
  params to your db string for it to return type time instead of a string
  (use ?parseTime=true, default is false)

You can use tools that were written by the community, to offload the overhead:

- A minimalistic wrapper around database/sql, [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx), uses similar way internally   with reflection.
- If you need more functionality, try using an "orm": [gorp](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp), [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm).

If you interested in diving deeper check out:

- Using reflection in sqlx package, [sqlx.go](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/master/sqlx.go) line 560
- Data type conversion in database/sql package, [convert.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/database/sql/convert.go) line 86

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is create a struct that models your data.

**Note: I am using MS SQLServer

So lets say you want to get a user

```
type User struct {
    ID int `json:"id,omitempty"`
    UserName string `json:"user_name,omitempty"`
    ...
}
```

then you can do this

```
func GetUser(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var r Role
    params := mux.Vars(req)

    db, err := sql.Open("mssql", "server=ServerName")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err1 := db.QueryRow("select Id, UserName from [Your Datavse].dbo.Users where Id = ?", params["id"]).Scan(&r.ID, &r.Name)
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err1)
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&r)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

Here are the imports I used

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "net/http"

    "log"

    "encoding/json"

    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)
```

This allowed me to get data from the database and get it into JSON.

This takes a while to code, but it works really well.

Comment: This is my preferred method as well, it's very easy to package in a project.

Answer (score 2):

Not in the Go distribution itself, but there is the wonderful [jmoiron/sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx):

`import "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"`

```
tableData := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)

for rows.Next() {
  entry := make(map[string]interface{})

  err := rows.MapScan(entry)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("SQL error: " + err.Error())
  }

  tableData = append(tableData, entry)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the data type that you are reading, then you can read into the data type without using generic interface.

Otherwise, there is no solution regardless of the language used due to nature of JSON itself.

JSON does not have description of composite data structures.  In other words, JSON is a generic key-value structure.  When parser encounters what is supposed to be a specific structure there is no identification of that structure in JSON itself.  For example, if you have a structure User the parser would not know how a set of key-value pairs maps to your structure User.

The problem of type recognition is usually addressed with document schema (a.k.a. XSD in XML world) or explicitly through passed expected data type.

Comment: I recommend considering a better storage format.  If GO application is the only one working with data, GOB file format will work well.  If other languages are involved a formal XSD approach will work.

If you have a case of Department contains a user and user is of type Teacher or a Student, then the easy way to deal with it is to store it in 2 parts.  Add UserType (of type string) to department and store Department with user type.  Then use UserType to load known type of user.  Department - User example is a perfect demo of JSON limits.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to go about being able to get an arbirtrary and generic []map[string]interface{} from these query libraries is to populate an array of interface pointers with the same size of the amount of columns on the query, and then pass that as a parameter on the scan function:

```
// For example, for the go-mssqldb lib:

queryResponse, err := d.pool.Query(query)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer queryResponse.Close()

// Holds all the end-results
results := []map[string]interface{}{}

// Getting details about all the fields from the query
fieldNames, err := queryResponse.Columns()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

// Creating interface-type pointers within an array of the same
// size of the number of columns we have, so that we can properly
// pass this to the "Scan" function and get all the query parameters back :)
var scanResults []interface{}
for range fieldNames {
    var v interface{}
    scanResults = append(scanResults, &v)
}

// Parsing the query results into the result map
for queryResponse.Next() {

    // This variable will hold the value for all the columns, named by the column name
    rowValues := map[string]interface{}{}

    // Cleaning up old values just in case
    for _, column := range scanResults {
        *(column.(*interface{})) = nil
    }

    // Scan into the array of pointers
    err := queryResponse.Scan(scanResults...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Map the pointers back to their value and the associated column name
    for index, column := range scanResults {
        rowValues[fieldNames[index]] = *(column.(*interface{}))
    }
    results = append(results, rowValues)
}

return results, nil
```